# The array for multi select drop down is not referenced well and gives an error

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use a multi select drop down as explained [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-multiple-select) but one way or the other the items array is not properly defined.

This is my code for the friendselector component:

```
/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import MultiSelect from 'react-native-multiple-select';

export default class FriendSelector extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedItems: [],
      items: [
        {
          id: '92iijs7yta',
          name: 'Kenneth',
        },
        {
          id: 'a0s0a8ssbsd',
          name: 'Ann',
        },
        {
          id: '16hbajsabsd',
          name: 'Leen',
        },
        {
          id: 'nahs75a5sg',
          name: 'Kris',
        },
        {
          id: '667atsas',
          name: 'Steve',
        },
        {
          id: 'suudydjsjd',
          name: 'Sarah',
        },
      ],
    };
  }
  onSelectedItemsChange = selectedItems => {
    this.setState({selectedItems});
  };

  render() {
    const {selectedItems} = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <MultiSelect
          hideTags
          items={this.items}
          uniqueKey="id"
          ref={component => {
            this.multiSelect = component;
          }}
          onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChange}
          selectedItems={selectedItems}
          selectText="Pick friend(s)"
          searchInputPlaceholderText="Search..."
          onChangeInput={text => console.log(text)}
          tagRemoveIconColor="#CCC"
          tagBorderColor="#CCC"
          tagTextColor="#CCC"
          selectedItemTextColor="#CCC"
          selectedItemIconColor="#CCC"
          itemTextColor="#000"
          displayKey="name"
          searchInputStyle={{color: '#CCC'}}
          submitButtonColor="#CCC"
          submitButtonText="Submit"
        />
        <View>
          {this.multiSelect &&
            this.multiSelect.getSelectedItemsExt(selectedItems)}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

which is similar as in this tutorial, I did change some references to items with state - this to connect things to one another. Still the items are not loaded in items={this.items} I have the feeling.

Does anyone know why?

This is the error:

[image: error message]

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items` prop is getting an undefined value because it's assigned `this.items` which doesn't exist in your class.

Change `items={this.items}` to `items={this.sate.items}` it makes more sense.

Another solution is to declare `items` array outside of the state.

Comment: Thanks that did it, I should have figured it out myself since I added the this. reference everywhere else!